# iOS SDK navigation controller: Autmoatically close/dismiss child view?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, dismiss, iphone

How can I close the child view automatically? My situation: I have a navigation controller and if I click onto an item in the root view a detail view appears. Now I want to close this detail view automatically?

Regards, Daniel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean programmatically? You can call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.